# Error in reading TSV file

Tags: r, csv, import

I am trying to read a tab-delimited file with 1000 obs. of 19 variables, using the function
`metrics<-read.delim("E:/1/3/metrics.tab")`.
It has a mistake in reading the fourth variables (the picture link) in some rows, so, in a few rows, I only got 18 variables:

```
missing read one column in some rows
```

It looks like this:

```
post_published_sql  likes
2015/1/9 1:00         5
2015/1/8 1:00         38
48                    48
2014/12/31 17:00      10
```

this one will be easier to understand

```
post_message picture             link   link_domain post_published  post_published_unixpost_
***brand   https://fbcdn-sphotos-  https://www.facebook.co facebook.com 2015-01-09T00:00:17+0000 
***brand   https://fbcdn-sphotos-  https://www.facebook.co facebook.com 2015-01-09T00:00:18+0000 
***brand   https://fbcdn-sphotos-  facebook.com 2015-01-09T00:00:18+0000
***brand   https://fbcdn-sphotos-  https://www.facebook.co facebook.com 2015-01-09T00:00:18+0000
```

Comment: What sort of mistake or error? Please edit that into your question.

Comment: Also, this isn't a reproducible example. Consider providing us a small dataset that illustrates the problem.

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy , I edit it, is it clear?

Comment: @Alex, sorry, I don't have enough reputation to add my pictures in the site, I list few data

Comment: Are you sure the file is tab-delimited? Your sample only was two columns do i don't understand what you're referring to when you talk about the fourth variable.

Comment: @MrFlick, I have 1000 rows and 19 variables(column) in the file named tab. I only can show few parts of it, I already change it, you can see the new one

Comment: It would appear a `https://www.facebook.co` is missing in the third line. If you're not willing to sort this by hand (insert an NA, for example), you'll have to use `readLines` and post process each line so that it will fit into a data.frame.

Comment: @Roman Luštrik It is a reallines in the file, I just post part of it because it is too long to display in the site.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help if I don't see actual data, sorry.